# select between 10 to 25 in mysql

Tags: mysql, database

I wanna to select all rows that **between 10 to 25** in my table
I have seen it is working with

```
SELECT TOP 10 * FROM table LIMIT 25;
```

but **SELECT TOP** not working on **MySQL** database

how can I write a query like that in my database?

please help me

Comment: `SELECT TOP` is a MSSQL thing. For MySQL, the `LIMIT` clause takes two parameters, or you can use the `OFFSET` keyword.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SELECT *
FROM Table
LIMIT 9,15

Check this..

Comment: This selects 15 arbitrarily picked rows, though. Rows in a database table are an unordered set. Without any `ORDER BY` clause the DBMS is allowed to return any 15 rows for this query.